# iOS Notification not playing sound

Tags: notifications, ios8

I've created a notification in my iOS app using iOS 8. The notification is correctly being displayed but it's not playing the sound, although `UIUserNotificationTypeSound` was registered and default sound name was specified. How can I make the sound play when I get the notification?

**Registering UIUserNotificationTypeSound**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]]

        return YES;
    }
```

**Setting default sound name**

```
localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested your code
But comparing to my code, I found you are not calling `[application registerForRemoteNotifications];` method

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Try this, I guess it will help you.

Comment: I believe the registerForRemoteNotifications method should be called only when you have notification object coming from the backend

Comment: @Noor Calling this will result in either application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: or application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: to be called on the application delegate. Note: these callbacks will be made only if the application has successfully registered for user notifications with registerUserNotificationSettings:, or if it is enabled for Background App Refresh.

Comment: I believe registerUserNotificationSettings was successful because in the setting, for the app, in notification, I can sound on and off, meaning it was successfully registered, am I right ?

Comment: Ok, are you getting device token without this method? I suppose you are not getting as because the delegate method to get device token won't get called. And I am not sure what are you doing, but how could you get remote notification without device token?